# What are the variable types for different colors in Chrome Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome developer console prints out the value of the variable `console.log(variable)`
 with different colors depending on the type of the variable. For example `string` values are black and `null` values grey.

1. Are there any documentation how these are defined?
2. Is it possible to modify custom colors for different value types? Like basic console messages: `console.log("%cBlue!", "color: blue;")`

The default colors of the types are fixed:

- String values are black
- null/undefined are grey
- Number values are blue
- Boolean values are blue
- Object/Array values are black (arrow in front)
- Object/Array properties are purple
- Object/Array property string values are red (quotations)

You can modify the output on some types (strings, integers, floats) with formatter but you have to know the type before hand: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object

> It seems that currently its not possible to have custom colors for
>   types with automatic type detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any documentation how these are defined?

Yes. You can check all the console apis provided by devtools [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference).

> Is it possible to modify custom colors for different value types?

No. You can only use the apis. APIs are not generic to add your own colors or formats. Based on the type of logs or whatever use the appropriate apis. like `console.log` or `console.dirxml` etc check the link for more apis.

Comment: Couldn't find the value types and colors for console.log. And yes, you can modify colors in console, for example: console.log("%cBlue!", "color: blue;");

Comment: Yep, you can do that to print string with your own css styles like `console.log("%csome text!", "color: Orange; font-weight:bold;text-decoration: underline;");` check the formatters here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object. But you cannot config or change the default behavior as said in question **string values are black and null values grey.** As the document itself says, its only for strings **String substitution and formatting**. so changing color for number/null/undefined is not in our control.

Answer (score -1):

Follow chrome doc to get all info related to console

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks